# How to add elements in a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, addition

To be honest, i don't really know how to properly explain what i want, so i better show it.
Basically what i want to do is add elements from 2 different 2D lists

```
a = [[5, 4, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8]]

b = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6, 2]]
```

And i wan't to merge them in a 2D array named c, so it should look something like this:

```
c = [[6, 6, 9, 9], [9, 11, 12, 10]]
```

I looked around, but sum and zip functions didn't give me the desired output. Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple list comprehension and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) will be sufficient, Use:

```
c = [[x + y for x, y in zip(s1, s2)] for s1, s2 in zip(a, b)]
```

Result:

```
#print(c)
[[6, 6, 9, 9], [9, 11, 12, 10]]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeking is essentially matrix addition:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[5, 4, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8]])
b = np.array([[1, 2, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6, 2]])
c = a + b
```

Where "array" is numpy's vector and matrix object, so when you return "c", you should see

```
>>> c
array ([[6, 6, 9, 9],
       [9, 11, 12, 10]])
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact I could do this by using two *zip* functions, one inside another.

```
c = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
  array = []
  for e1, e2 in zip(x, y):
    array.append(e1+e2)
  c.append(array)
print(c)
```

The output would be:

```
[[6, 6, 9, 9], [9, 11, 12, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the result in a new array, I'm creating a new matrix C as a copy of A.
So that i can easily add B to A.
You can do this:

```
c = a
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range(0,len(a[0]):
        c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j] 
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to merge 2 arrays.

```
c = [[a[i][j] + b[i][j] for j in range(len(a[0]))] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop to solve the problem.

```
a = [[5, 4, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8]]
b = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6, 2]]
c=[]

l=len(a)
for i in range(l):
    temp=[]
    l2=len(a[i])
    for j in range(l2):
        p=a[i][j]+b[i][j]
        temp.append(p)
    c.append(temp)

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for this.

from builtins import len

def insaneSum(x,y):

```
newTable = x #creates a copie of your first array
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(x):
    while j < len(x[i]):

        newTable[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[i][j] #replaces value of copie for the sum

        j = j+1
    i = i+1

return newTable
```

a = [[5, 4, 5, 4], [4, 5, 6, 8]]
b = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [5, 6, 6, 2]]

c = insaneSum(a,b)
print(c)